# java program with methods and boolean

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class ProcessNumbers
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive: ") ;
    int num = in.nextInt() ;
    boolean result = shouldProcess(num);
    String result1 = String.valueOf(result) ;
}
public static boolean shouldProcess(int n)
{
    if (n>=6 && n<12)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    } 
 }
    public static boolean processInput(boolean result2)
 {
 if (result2 == true)
 {
     System.out.println("Yes") ; 
 }
 else 
 {
     System.out.println("No") ;
 }
 return result2 ;
}


}
```

now I am getting the output which is partially right but has forgot the yes or no output in the second method

```
Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive:
```

when it should also include the yes or not output

Comment: **Please do not edit your question into a totally different question**.  You asked a different question, and others answered it.  Now you've changed the question so that the answer no longer makes sense.  StackOverflow is designed to provide answers to questions that people can look up later, and you just sabotaged it.  Please revert your edit and **ask a new question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending in a `boolean` value in the method parameter of `processInput` but you are catching it as a `String`. You need to change it to `boolean`. Further, you want to check if its value is `true` with equal signs like below:

```
public static void processInput(boolean result2)
 {
     if (result2 == true)
     {
         System.out.println("Yes") ; 
     }
     else 
     {
         System.out.println("No") ;
     }
 }
```

EDIT 2:
Also, you need to change `String result1 = String.valueOf(result);` to `processInput(result);`

EDIT 3:
If you want the number printed too that you just entered and then you want a "yes" or "no", then between `int num = in.nextInt();` and `boolean result = shouldProcess(num);`, add this line: `System.out.println(num);`

Comment: You're missing a brace :^)

Comment: okay i have updated my code but still not getting the yes or no output

Comment: @javahelp sorry can you explain what exact output you want?

Comment: if the boolean result is true, that means its inbetween and including 6-12, i want it to print yes, but if it isnt i will print no

Comment: okay I edited my code. Take a look at it now. Basically I changed two things. Changed the signature of the method from String to void and 2nd it doesn't return anything.

Comment: it still wont output that yes or no unfortunately  still just the please enter an integer

Comment: Oh I just noticed another mistake in your edited code. Check my answer now and make those changes

Comment: okay thank you very much it finally works  thanks for your time

Comment: Thx glad I could help

Comment: in my output i get Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive: Yes           shouldnt i get Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive: 10    which is my input that i put in

Comment: so you want a number instead of "yes" or "no"

Comment: i want the number that i inputed to be after Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive:

Comment: then after below a yes

Comment: @javahelp check my answer now

Answer (score 1):

There's apparently some code missing, so I'm guessing this is just part of the full thing. So I will only tackle your output issue.

I won't talk about the code in: `public static boolean processInput(boolean result2)`, because you're not running it anywhere in your main method `public static void main( String[] args )` anyway.

Now, in your code at:

```
public static boolean shouldProcess(int n)
```

if you look at your code, you are assigning the value of the `boolean` to the new `String result1`, so `result1` now has the new value, but you are not running its output anywhere, so there's no way the program can guess you want to output that value. You need to assign the output:

```
System.out.print(result1);
```

However, if you only want to output the `boolean`, there's no need to assign that `boolean` value to a new `String` and then output the new `String`, you could just:

```
System.out.print(result);
```

Unless you're going to use that value somewhere else where creating a new variable would arguably be a good choice.

Also, it seems you want to return either a "Yes" or "No" on your class: `public static boolean processInput(boolean result2)`.

Remember a class that does not return a value, but rather executes a code, has to be written as `void`. In other words, your:

```
public static boolean processInput(boolean result2)
```

should really be:

```
public static void processInput(boolean result2)
```

Because if not, you are just making your program `return result2;`, which in this case can only be either `true` or `false`. By adding `void` to the class, makes the class understand it will be executing your `System.out.print` code, rather than returning a value for you to use. But also, depends on what you want to afterwards.